# which better to use for handling requests aspx or ashx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, httprequest

i am creating a httpRequest handler to download files ..
my question is which better to use aspx or ashx ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based only on the information in your question it seems to me that you should create an ASP.NET Handler (.ashx) class since you don't require the overhead of the full ASP.NET page life-cycle.

The difference between a page and a handler is that the handler is a more light-weight class which doesn't offer all the "stages" of a normal page. As always, the answer as to which one to use depends entirely on what exactly you need from the framework, in terms of request life-cycle.

If you're interested (and you should be if you're asking the question..) read more about [ASP.NET Page Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479007.aspx) and [about the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Generic handler (ASHX) is much better and more light-weight.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, page is a handler too, because Page class implements IHttpHandler, although it hides the IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest implementation by explicit implementation.

Use page if you need to show page UI, use handler if you need to make some processing on the server side and maybe return some kind of simple response (optionally).

I hope this makes sense.